# iTextSharp PdfCopy breaks PDF for Foxit Reader (TypeError: Cannot read property '__validate' of undefined)

Tags: pdf, itext

I'm working on some code to concatenate PDF's using iTextSharp. At this stage I've simplified the code to concatenate just one PDF:

```
public static void Concat(string outputFilePath, string inputFilePath)
{
    using (var document = new Document())
    {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(outputFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        using (var copier = new PdfCopy(document, fileStream))
        {
            copier.SetMergeFields();
            document.Open();

            var reader = new PdfReader(inputFilePath);
            copier.AddDocument(reader);
            copier.AddJavaScript(reader.JavaScript);

            copier.Close();
        }
        document.Close();
    }
}
```

I have a particular PDF that breaks with this code:

- [Input file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nhy7av9b37uwowl/in1.pdf?dl=0)
- [Output file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g58fe27p0row8qc/out.pdf?dl=0)

The input file works fine in Foxit Reader: all the fields are read-only except for the large field at the bottom which can be edited.
The output file however, does not work right in Foxit Reader. Editing the bottom field and clicking elsewhere yields the error `TypeError: Cannot read property '__validate' of undefined`

I've compared the structure of the AcroForm fields, but I cannot identify which difference would cause this error. I also tried to find out which part of [the Javascript](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tolhjj5wk4lmzpv/script.js?dl=0) is causing the error, but as far as I can tell the error does not happen inside the PDF's javascript, but rather when Foxit Reader tries to call `__validate()` on an entry in `elements` which does not exist.

The file seems to be working fine using Adobe Reader.

Any ideas?

Comment: When I edit the `out.pdf` file I see a giant form field covering everything. After moving that off and looking at field `c57` which is the big text area I can see the following JavaScript which is probably what is causing your issues: `try{event.rc = elements["c56"].__validate(event.value,null);
}catch(e){app.alert(e.toString());}`

Comment: What do you use to edit the PDF?  
I'm not sure where that Javascript code that you refer to comes from (from PDF or generated by PDF reader/editor) but it should not fail because `elements["c56"]` is assigned in the PDF's (main?) Javascript.

Comment: Copying PDF pages using `PdfCopy` with `SetMergeFields` introduces certain structural differences: For merging the field definitions have to be transformed into a unified structure; this transformation makes sure that the displayed fields are equivalently defined as AcroForm fom fields. This transformation can make some difference in the object model available to JavaScript, though. I would propose manipulating such forms with heavy-duty JavaScript interaction only using a `PdfStamper`.

Comment: *The file seems to be working fine using Adobe Reader.* - The JavaScript object model for PDF viewers unfortunately is not as well standardized as the core PDF file format, there is no specification by an origanization like ISO, IETF, ETSI, etc., but merely a manufacturer provided reference "Adobe JavaScript for Acrobat API Reference". Thus, different PDF viewers with JavaScript support can behave somewhat differently.

Comment: @mkl `PdfStamper` can't be used to concatenate multiple PDF's, can it? 
I would still like to know where/why the error occurs, but it seems very hard to trace. If Chris' hunch is right in that `elements["c56"].__validate()` is the code that's failing, I cannot see why, since `elements["c56"]` is instantiated in the PDF's javascript and has the `__validate()` function assigned to it.

Comment: *`PdfStamper` can't be used to concatenate multiple PDF's* - it is not designed for that, true, What is the nature of the other documents to be concatenated? Are they forms, too? Or fixed content only? In the latter case, `PdfStamper` might be used. In the former I have no idea.

Comment: The second document looks simpler, but also contains AcroFields. The application is generic, so we can't really rely on the nature of the documents. 
For now I'm trying to figure out exactly how the javascript is crashing in order to take things from there.

Comment: I've logged this at Foxit support as a bug in the Foxit Reader.